# How long does it take to get a carte de sejour from Antony sub prefecture, France?

Tags: resident-permit, france

I received my recepisse in July 2nd . It has already been 3 months. I want to go to India after my internship ends in October 31st and I cannot book the flight tickets till the card arrives. Can anyone give me an estimate of how much time it takes in Antony prefecture?